# Need client machine's output of a windows command in php

Tags: php, cmd

I want to fetch the output of a windows command in php of a client computer(from which computer I'll browse). Below code is showing the output of the server computer.

```
<?php  
// Turn on output buffering  
ob_start();  
//Get the ipconfig details using system commond  
system('ipconfig /all');  
// Capture the output into a variable  
$mycomsys=ob_get_contents();  
// Clean (erase) the output buffer  
ob_clean();    
echo $mycomsys;   
?>
```

It's printing all the info of command ipconfig /all of a server pc. But I need the info the client PC's info from whcih I am browsing the web.

Thanks

Comment: This would only get the servers IP information not the client. Because you are running the code on your local PC you will see your local information (which will be the same as the server information).

Comment: hi
is there any way to run command on client machine in php. either javascript/jquery?

Comment: php is SERVERSIDE ... JavaScript / VBS might be executable on clientside

Comment: You want to do something that no sane browser implementation would ever let you do. See details in my answer below!

Comment: and now, just for a moment, imagine the security implications of *any website* running an *arbitrary command* on the machine of *whoever browses to it*. and when you have done that, you will know why it is not, and should not, be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You want your website to execute random commands on a client computer. That's not possible. If it were the internet would be a very dangerous place to browse indeed.

Imagine for a second what would happen in every site you visited had the ability to run commands on your computer. Web administrators could do anything they wanted! View your files; read your personal information; trash everything!

For this reason, no browser will ever let you do what you want to do.